# How does mongodb handle HTML5/Javascript typed arrays?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb

I am interacting with a mongodb through Javascript.

Is there any difference between the following two statements?

```
myCollection.insert({tiles: new Int32Array(256)});
myCollection.insert({tiles: new Array(256)});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's very different.

The first using `Int32Array`, which isn't a JavaScript type that the current driver uses/understands, instead becomes projected into an object with properties following the indices of the array:

```
"tiles" : { "0" : 0, "1" : 0, "2" : 0.... }
```

The second translates to an Array in MongoDB, of [type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-bson-types) `Null`.

```
"tiles": [ null, null, null .... ]
```

So, the first does not remain as an array, while the second one does.